# Styling radio button - background color

Tags: html, css

I want that the background inner color of the radio buttons are the same as the background color of the container, and no border around the selection.

I tried with background color, color, but didn't work.
In the HTML the buttons are not into a form tag, by now I don't need it, I've even tried to add it to see if something changed but without results, any idea?

I know i can just put normal buttons styling easier, but i want the "one-only" selection. I could code it in JS but if possible to style the radio button is better!

Current situation: [image: actual situation]

Desired result: [image: result]

```css
.radioButton {
  background-color: rgb(37, 45, 68);
  border-radius: 50px;
}

input {
  accent-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioButton">
  <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" checked="true">
  <input type="radio" id="color2" name="color">
  <input type="radio" id="color3" name="color">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at appearance: none?

Comment: You can't do much to style the actual browser default buttons. You essentially have to hide the default appearance and create your own styles on top of it. Many, many tutorials online.

Comment: @ralph.m nowadays you can use appearance: none and style quite a bit your own way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS appearance: none to remove the browser default styling and then add in your own:

```html
<style>
  .radioButton {
    background-color: rgb(37, 45, 68);
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  
  input {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  
  input:checked {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
<div class="radioButton">
  <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" checked="true">
  <input type="radio" id="color2" name="color">
  <input type="radio" id="color3" name="color">
</div>
```

Comment: This solution perfectly fits, thank you so much! I dind't know i could completely delete the style of an element with appearance: none and restyle it as i want, it will be really usefull for many other projects, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Hide `<input>` then add `<span>`, styling the `<span>`.

Remember to wrap `<span>` and `<input>` in `<label>` so the radio input will be checked when `<span>` was clicked.

```css
.radioButton {
  background-color: rgb(37, 45, 68);
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input+span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: rgb(37, 45, 68);
}

input:checked+span {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioButton">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color" checked="true">
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="color2" name="color" checked="true">
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" id="color3" name="color" checked="true">
        <span></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It works thank you, but applying this solution i need to style again the labels. I typed them just over the input section inside a div (in the image the numbers 1 2 3 are the labels of each button, i just didn't post that part of code). I did it so it was easier for me to aplly them over the button insted of near, as in the pic. By the way, your code gave me ad idea how to solve a problem i have on another project, so big thanks!!